# Is my data overwritten?

Tags: 14.04, 14.10

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and was attempting to do the upgrade to 14.10 without losing my home folder and it's contents.... however something went wrong because after rebooting I was not able to access anything or boot into Ubuntu at all.
I used my Live disc to restore back to 14.04 without formatting so it deleted and reinstalled my Ubuntu but also deleted my home folder and gave me a default home folder.  This was last night, and I have made a point to do as little as possible so not to write new data.

How can I recover my old home folder? I'm not very good with command line for something this complex so I would prefer a GUI based application to restore the data of my old home folder.

*ADD
I've attempted to do a restore using gparted, but my partition table was not changed as it all happened within the existing partition table.  I lost nearly 2 TB of data, but haven't written anything besides the OS since it was deleted and now all of that is free space on the same partition.  I took a look at the data recovery guide but it is mostly for recovering entire partitions and that's not the case here.

Comment: Sounds like you over wrote your data. Upgrades are designed to go well, but, as you can see there are occasional problems. You can try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from the live cd then chroot the system and check /home. Chroot is essentially the procedure described on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery in the section Update Failure. In addition to this guide mount /home too.
If you can't see a folder with your previous username in /home then you lost your data.
During recovery if you choose the same username as before then don't even bother to try the procedure above because your data is gone anyway.